# How to preset the Value of a TNumberBox at DesignTime to a specific Integer value?

Tags: delphi, vcl, delphi-11-alexandria

In a 32-bit VCL Application in Windows 10 in Delphi 11 Alexandria, I try to use a `TNumberBox` control:

```
object nbRowheight: TNumberBox
  Left = 20
  Top = 225
  Width = 77
  Height = 23
  Hint = 'Set the Row height.'
  Anchors = []
  MinValue = 18.000000000000000000
  TabOrder = 8
  SpinButtonOptions.ButtonWidth = 20
  SpinButtonOptions.Placement = nbspInline
end
```

At design time, I try to preset it with a value of 21 in the ObjectInspector. But as soon as I enter 21 in the ObjectInspector's `Value` field and then press the Enter key, the `Value` switches back to **0**!

So how can I preset the Value of a TNumberBox at DesignTime to a specific Integer value?

Update: Obviously, the issue is caused by the `MaxValue` left at its default value of 0: If I set `MaxValue` to e.g. 32 in ObjectInspector, then I can enter the `Value` 21 in ObjectInspector without problems. But doesn't a default `MaxValue` of 0 mean that it is indeterminate (i.e., that it can be any value)?

Comment: It sounds like a bug... `MaxValue = 0` means "no max value", for all controls I've used. Unfortunately I don't have `TNumberBox` on my Delphi XE7 so I can't try

Comment: Unfortunately, this component is poorly documented, so there is no way to know whether this is a bug or working as designed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Well, the developer's intention becomes fairly apparent if you look at the source code: `if (AValue > FMaxValue) and (FMinValue <> FMaxValue) then
      AValue := FMaxValue`. Clearly, there's an effective `FDoRestrict := FMinValue <> FMaxValue` condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if `MinValue = 0` and `MaxValue = 0`, there is *no* restriction.

This makes sense and is a fairly common convention in APIs.

However, to be absolutely sure, you should *always* consult the documentation. In this case, the documentation for [`MaxValue`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.NumberBox.TCustomNumberBox.MaxValue) says this:

> Embarcadero Technologies does not currently have any additional information.

*That's* a bug. Documentation is vitally important.

My initial guess was that `MinValue = 0` and `MaxValue = 0` means "no restriction" and any other pair means that there is a restriction, given by the bounds specified by these properties. So if you set one of them, you must set both.

In your case, you set `MinValue` but fail to set `MaxValue`. Since you want no upper bound, you can achieve this by setting `MaxValue` to the property's greatest possible value. (Which, since this property is of type `Extended`, depends on whether your app is 32-bit or 64-bit. But in practice, I bet something like `1E20` will work well for you.)

Now, was my guess correct?

Kind of.

Looking at the `TNumberBox` source code, I see that there is no restriction [iff](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/iff) `MinValue = MaxValue` (not `MinValue = 0` and `MaxValue = 0` as I had guessed).

IMMNSHO, this is a strange and bad design choice. I mean, if I set `MinValue` and `MaxValue` to `20` (at runtime, because of the state of the program), I expect the value to be fixed to `20`. But no! Now it can be any value.

IMMNSHO, this is a bug.

Comment: And in 2022, when a byte is cheap, there is no reason not to have a boolean `DoRestrict` property instead of relying on a magic combination of the min and max values. Indeed, perhaps the current state of your program requires that the minimum and maximum values *are* both `0` at some time?

Comment: "*Since you want no upper bound, you can achieve this by setting `MaxValue` to `2147483647`, the greatest possible `Integer` value*" - except that the `(Min|Max)Value` properties for this component use `Extended`, not `Integer`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Gah... Why do kids these days like floating point so much...

Comment: Why doesn't `TNumberBox` have a `ValueType` property that specifies the Type of `Value` (Integer, Extended, etc.)? Couldn't we also have a `Boolean` Value Type?

Comment: Is `TNumberBox` an Experimental control?

Comment: It seems `TNumberBox` is a new control that was added in Delphi 10.4 Sydney. This is most likely the reason why documentation on this control is still lacking the needed information. As for different value types based on documentation it seems that `TNumberBox` it is built on top of [TCustomNumberBox](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/Vcl.NumberBox.TCustomNumberBox) that does have multiple value properties for multiple value types. I'm guessing the design idea is to publish the needed value type in the final components that do extend from this one `TCustomNumberBox`.

Comment: @user1580348 `TNumberBox` has separate properties for different data types: `Value` (`Extended`), `ValueCurrency`, `ValueFloat`, and `ValueInt`.